# Prove $|(a+b) \log (a+b) - a \log a| \leq b \log (\frac{1}{b})$

Tags: logarithms, proof-explanation

Can you prove or point me where I can reference the following assertion?

$|(a+b) \log (a+b) - a \log a| \leq b \log (\frac{1}{b}); a \in [0,1), b \in (0,1], a+b \in [0,1]$

Comment: How about $a=1$? You get $|b \log(b)| \leq b \log (\frac{1}{b})$, which is false

Comment: @talbi Is $|(1+b)\log (1+b)| \le b\log(\frac1b)$ true? I'm not too sure

Comment: @player3236 you get $|b\log(b)| \leq b \log(\frac{1}{b})$. $b$ is positive (because of the $\log$) so you get $|\log (b)| \leq \log(\frac{1}{b})$. This is false. (at least for all $b$ which I assume is what is being asked here)

Comment: @player3236 Oh, I didn't notice the $1+b$. Still, I think its fair to claim this is false for all $b$ (the inequality holds for $b < 0.525$)

Comment: I will edit my question because I forgot to include the domain $a, a+b \in [0,1], b \in (0,1] $

Comment: I know that in the domain, $\underset{a}{\max} a \log a = 1/\mathrm{e}$, and also  $\underset{a}{\max} b \log (1/b) = 1/\mathrm{e}$.  My idea was to derive both sides to see how the derived curve behaves.

Comment: I am seing this in a proof and this statement is not well explained. But I think its proof has to do with prooving that if $\phi(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0, x=0\\
x \log (1/x), 0<x<1/\mathrm{e}\\
1/\mathrm{e}, x>1/\mathrm{e}
\end{cases}$, and then try to prove: $|(a+b) \log (a+b) - a \log a| \leq \phi (a+b) \leq b \log (1/b)$

Comment: I am not certain.

Comment: Still incorrect: $(a,b)=(2/7,7/10)$.

Comment: Graphing the difference $k=|(a+b)\ln(a+b)-a\ln(a)|+b\ln(b)$ maybe helps figuring it out https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yn9f9vt0ma. By adjusting $k$ it seems the shapes union covers the interior of the triangle but not the top crescent (area above curve at  $k=0$) for instance a point like $A=(\frac 15, \frac 34)$ is never included. Also is point $B=(\frac 15,\frac 1e)$ reached for $k=-\frac 1e$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can rewrite the given inequality as,

$$\left\lvert\log{\frac{(a+b)^{a+b}}{a^{a}}}\right\rvert \leq log{(\frac{1}{b})^{b}}$$

Now since $$a+b \geq a $$so $$(a+b)^{(a+b)}\geq a^{a}$$
hence, $$\left\lvert\log{\frac{(a+b)^{a+b}}{a^{a}}}\right\rvert =log{\frac{(a+b)^{a+b}}{a^{a}}}$$
so thee inequality is now,
$$log{\frac{(a+b)^{a+b}}{a^{a}}}\leq log{(\frac{1}{b})^{b}}$$
since logarithm is an increasing function,
$$\frac{(a+b)^{a+b}}{a^{a}}\leq (\frac{1}{b})^{b}$$
$$\frac{(a+b)^{a+b}}{a^{a}}\leq \frac{1}{b^{b}}$$
$$\frac{(a+b)^{a+b}}{a^{a}}\geq b^{b}$$
$$(a+b)^{a}(a+b)^{b} \geq a^{a}b^{b}$$
Now for $$(a+b) \in [0,1],a \in [0,1),b \in (0,1]$$
$$(a+b)^{a} \geq a^{a}\ and\ (a+b)^{b} \geq b^{b}$$
so$$(a+b)^{a}(a+b)^{b} \geq a^{a}b^{b}$$
is true.
Therefore the given inequality is true.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Vlad in the conclusion that the inequality does not always hold true. Here I try to visualize the problem.

All the terms in the inequality are of the form $ x.ln x $ (even on the right side, $ b.ln(1/b) = - b.ln b $). Note that since $ a , b , a+b $ are less than or equal to 1, their logarithms are negative. Also note that logarithms are undefined at zero, so the domains of $ a $ and $ a+b $ should exclude zero. Let's take a look at the function $ f(x) = x.lnx $ in the interval $ (0,1] $ :

[[image: <span class=]$ f(x) = x.lnx $" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKd5n.png)

The function has a minimum somewhere in the interval. We can calculate where it is, and we will see that it helps us find a counterexample, a set of numbers for which the inequality does not hold. The minimum is where the first derivative is zero.
$$ f'(x) = lnx + 1 = 0 $$
This happens at $ x = 1/e $  (because $ ln(e^{-1})=-1 $). In the above graph I have marked this vertical line in red.

We know this point is a minimum because (in addition to the visualization) $ f''(x) = 1/x $ is positive in the interval $ (0,1] $ , which means that $ f'(x) $ is increasing all through the interval. This, in turn, means that the slope is negative before it reaches zero, and positive afterwards. Hence, minimum!

At this $ x $ the function has the greatest absolute value in the interval.

Now let's look at another point: $ f(1) = 1.ln(1) = 0 $. At $ x = 1 $ the function has the least absolute value in the interval. Therefore,  $ f(1) - f(1/e) $ has the largest absolute value for the difference between function values of two points in the interval. This leads us to a conclusion about the validity of the inequality. Any other value for the function over this interval is smaller, in absolute value, than $ |f(1) - f(1/e)| $ . This is also true for $ b = 1 - a = 1 - 1/e $ . The line $ x = 1 - 1/e $ is shown in blue in the graph, and it visually confirms that in this case, $ |f(a+b) - f(a)| > |f(b| $ , or, for $a = 1/e$ and $b=1 - 1/e$ :
$$ |(a+b).ln(a+b) - a.ln a| > |b.ln b| = b.ln(1/b) $$
Voila our counterexample.